# What process is behind Youtube's ability to prevent mobile Browser/App video background playback?

Tags: background, video-streaming

Lately I have been wondering what is involved in preventing the Browser/App background video playback feature that is part of iOS and Android.

Recently, Youtube also moved the playback functionality (That I understand is part of the OS) behind a paywall. A few years ago you could play videos in the background without trouble. Then the feature's availability started being exploited and eventually moved behind Youtube's subscription service.

I'm curios if this is a decision by the mobile developers to prevent battery drain, or are mobile OS developers allowing app developers to exploit the background playback feature that, from my understanding, is/was part of the mobile device's OS.

I'm asking on stackoverflow because it seems like Developers would understand what is happening here. Does anyone know, or could point me to information that describes the reasoning behind this move?

Comment: This is a purely business decision.  Note that if you pay them more, you can keep playing videos.  It's all about content licensing.

Comment: Are content providers exploiting technical features of the hardware and putting those features behind paywalls, and is mobile device OS developers working with the content industry to make this happen?